# store unknown size array in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I have in mysql database a datetime value (2015-01-01 12-54-32) which I use to know the date in which the library subscriber reserved a book it is easy to store one datetime value in database but the problem is i don't know how many books the subscriber will reserve from the library could be 1 or could be 5 , the question is how do i store it in database as array ?

Comment: How about storing them as several rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to store this in a database is to use a junction table.  Something like this:

```
create table BookReservations (
    BookReservationId int auto_increment primary key,
    SubscriberId int not null,
    BookId int not null,
    ReservationDate date not null,
    constraint fk_bookreservations_subscriberid foreign key (SubscriberId) references Subscribers(SubscriberId),
    constraint fk_bookreservations_bookid foreign key (BookId) references Books(BookId)
);
```

(Clearly, this just suggests names for entities and columns not mentioned in the question.)

Note that this table defines the foreign key relationships among the tables as well as storing the data.  This allows the database to ensure relational integrity.  MySQL does not (currently) allow such definitions for string or JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store multiple books in one field you can json_encode the array everytime you store it and then json_decode it again when you select it from the db.

But the better approach is to create a book_subscribe table where you can store as many as you like per subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize` and `unserialize` to covert arrays and add it in your database column. Your question makes me think you have a database design issue. Take a look at one-to-many relationships (eg. one customer, several books)